# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException in struts spring hibernate example

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts

I am trying to run spring struts and hibernate example in tomcat6 , i am getting following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/database/spring/HibernateSessionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:295)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.init(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:225)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:871)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:359)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
```

HibernateSessionFactory.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->

    <bean id="sessionFactory" 
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
          <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
             <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                   <value>com/mkyong/customer/hibernate/Customer.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
         </property>    

    </bean>
    </beans>
```

Customer.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 20 April 2010 8:33:09 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.5.Beta -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer" table="customer" catalog="mkyong">
        <id name="customerId" type="long">
            <column name="CUSTOMER_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="address" type="string">
            <column name="ADDRESS" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="CREATED_DATE" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

SpringBeans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <import resource="config/database/spring/DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="config/database/spring/HibernateSessionFactory.xml"/>

    <!-- Beans Declaration -->
    <import resource="com/mkyong/customer/spring/CustomerBean.xml"/>


</beans>
```

Directory Structure for Customer.java

```
StrutsSpringExample
    src/main/java
        com.mkyong.customer
            model
              Customer.java
```

Package for Customer.java

```
com.mkyong.customer.model
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, the following class cannot be found on the classpath:

```
com.mkyong.customer.model.Customer
```

Comment: Pelase check edited question to see directory structure for Customer.java file.

Comment: In your directory structure, is there a single directory called `com.mykong.customer` or is that actually three nested directories.  If you open your WAR file, `Customer.class` should be in `WEB-INF/classes/com/mkyong/customer/model/`?

Comment: @chetan, is this the full stacktrace ? I mean is there any other exceptions happen prior to  `sessionFactory` bean creation ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is clear, `initializeBean` failed because that *Customer* class cannot be found.

Now you need to ensure that the Customer.class exists in the directory,

```
# find . -name Customer.class
./WEB-INF/classes/com/mkyong/customer/model/Customer.class
# pwd
/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/<your_webapp_context>
```

Also, ensure that you have all the require libraries place in the lib folder. Below are the one exists in my webapp lib folder. **Note**: when the libraries dependency are not met, you will get a lot of exception during war file deploy.

- antlr-2.7.2.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
- commons-chain-1.2.jar
- commons-digester-1.8.jar
- commons-io-1.1.jar
- commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- geronimo-jpa-2.0-spec.jar
- guava-11.0.1.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-3.6.4.Final.jar
- javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
- oro-2.0.8.jar
- postgresql-jdbc4-9.1.jar
- quartz-all-1.6.6.jar
- spring-beans-2.5.jar
- spring-context-2.5.jar
- spring-context-support-2.5.jar
- spring-core-2.5.jar
- spring-jdbc-2.5.jar
- spring-orm-2.5.jar
- spring-tx.jar
- spring-web-2.5.jar
- spring-webmvc-struts-2.5.jar
- struts-core-1.3.10.jar
- struts-extras-1.3.10.jar
- struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar
- struts-tiles-1.3.10.jar

I've done the tutorial few days ago with integration to PostgreSQL and it is working fine. If you want, I can upload my war file somewhere.